# Handling huge string with stringbuilder in C#

Tags: c#, string, stringbuilder

I want to replace the 2nd last character in the end of my string builder in an easy and efficient way (ie fast speed and less memory). The string will be about 200-300 mb I guess (not sure). How do I do it ? Will the answer change if the input string also has a newline at its end ?

Thanks.

Comment: Where is this string coming from? If its from a file.. I would suggest that you Seek to the end and replace the character by writing over the top of it. That saves a 300MB string being in memory..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`StringBuilder.Chars`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.chars.aspx) to overwrite a specific char in the `StringBuilder`:

```
// For example, replace 'x' into the 2nd to last char
stringBuilder[stringBuilder.Length-2] = 'x';
```

Answer (score 3):

`StringBuilder` uses an array of chars as its backing store. A simple

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder() ;
sb.Append( GetSomeEnormousString() ) ;

sb[ sb.Length - 2 ] = '*' ;
```

should do you.

Outside of any paging involved, it's a direct memory access.